# does a modalviewcontroller resignFirstResponder of the parentviews subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, first-responder, parentviewcontroller

in order to recognize if a user jumps from editing one textField to another by just touching another one instead of hitting the return button i implemented a method which gets called with the event "Editing did end".
i read this event also happens when, in this case a textField resignsFirstResponder.

Now whenever the user hase a multiple choice I present a modal View with a picker.
I have the problem whenever there is a multiple choice and the user switches textFields without hitting return this method gets called twice and I don know why!

is it possible that the modalviewcontroller resigns all FirstResponder of the parentView when it gets presented ?

Answer (score 0):

you can say

```
[myTextField1 resignFirstResponder];
[myTextField2 resignFirstResponder];
[myTextField3 resignFirstResponder];
```

before presenting your controller.

but i have a feeling there could be a better way to solve this if i can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: no this is no what I want! actually this is exactly what I do not want! cause my methode gets called I do something and it should not be called again unless the user typed something in the textField. if I call resignFirstResponder the method would be called again!

Comment: For text fields you are presenting modal controller with picker, you should return NO in textFieldShouldBeginEditing: method. So for such text fields, no keyboard will pop up.

Comment: that is not my problem. I do need the keyboard. Just wanted to know if is it possible that the modalviewcontroller resigns all FirstResponder of the parentView when it gets presented ?